# Arduino: In function `__vector_5': (.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__vector_5'

Tags: arduino, interrupt, attiny

I'm coming back to Arduino after a long hiatus, and I want to get as close to bare metal as possible while still using an Arduino Uno as an ISP. I decided that I'd start by using an ATTiny85 as a frequency counter, using TImer0 to count pulses on the T0 pin:

```
/*
 * ATTiny frequency counter
 *  Inputs: Frequency source (amplified to square wave) on T0 (ATTiny85 pin 7/PB2)
 *          16MHz Crystal (ATTiny85 pins 2,3)
 *  Outputs: Simple serial (ATTiny85 pin 6/PB1 as clock, 5/PB0 as data)
 *  
 *  Algorithm:
 *    For each 1 second cycle:
 *      Shift out previously recorded frequency 
 *      Intitalize Timer0OFC to 0
 *      Initialize Counter0 to 0
 *      At end of cycle, count how many times Counter0 overflowed
 *      Store value of Timer0OFC*256 + COunter0 to Frequency
 *   
 *   Transmission:
 *      To generate clock signal:
 *        Set compare OCR1A to value of TCNT1+1
 *        On interrupt of TCNT1=OCR1C:
 *        Set pin 6 low
 *        Set pin 5 to appropriate data value
 *        Set pin 6 high
 *   
 */
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/iotnx5.h>
//Register values
  void setupRegisters(void){
    //Timer 1: general timing
    PLLCSR=0x00;  //No PLL action wanted, counter1 recieves 16MHz system clock
    TCCR1=0x8B;   //Use clear on match, no pwm, no pin, divide by 10, 0b10001011
    OCR1C=125;    //Will clear on match
    OCR1A=255;    //Will be used to conduct 15kHz serial output routine
    TIMSK=0x16;   //enable overflow interruptS, match A interrupt, 0b00010010
    TIFR=0x00;    //Hardware reset bit 2 on overflow, and bit 4 on match
    TCNT1=0x00;   //Counter register
    //Timer 0: asynchronously counts frequency
    GTCCR=0x00;   //no halting, 0b00000000
    TCCR0A=0x00;  //no pin override functionality,0b00000000
    TCCR0B=0x08;  //Select rising edge on T0 pin, 0b00000111
    TCNT0=0x00;   //Counter register
    //I/O
    PORTB=0x01;    //Port B data register, 0b00000001
    DDRB=0x13;    //PB0 and PB1 as output, PB2 as input, 0b00010011
    PINB=0x00;    //   
    PCMSK=0x20;   //Pin 5 as data, pin 6 as clock,0x0010000
  }
//Global variables
  //General timing
  uint8_t Timer1OFC=0;  //Counts overflows of timer 1
  //For frequency counting
  uint32_t Timer0OFC=0;  //Counts overflows of timer 0
  uint32_t frequency=0; //Measured frequency
  uint8_t counter2=0;   //Divide TCNT1 by 125 for 1Hz cycle
//ISRs 
ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect){                   //Timer 1 overflow 0x0004
  if(Timer1OFC==125){                   //Will happen once a second with 16MHz crystal
    frequency=(Timer0OFC*256)+(TCNT0);  //Total number of pulses in 1 second period
    Timer1OFC=0;                        //To restart output bit counting
    Timer0OFC=0;TCNT0=0;                //Resets pulse counter
    OCR1A=1;                            //Start counting outbits
  }
  else{
    Timer1OFC++;                        //increments counter
  }
}
ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect){//Timer 0 Overflow 0x0005
  Timer0OFC++;  //increments counter
}
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect){//Timer 1 Match A 0x0003
  if(OCR1A<=16){                                //16-bit output
    PORTB=(PORTB&=0xFD)|(frequency>=(1<<15));   //Clock low, shifts msb out to PB0
    frequency=frequency<<1;                     //Shifts so that output bit next cycle is the next digit over
    OCR1A++;                                    //Primes, so that it matches the next time Timer 1 increments
    PORTB|=1<<1;                                //Set clock high (PB1)
  }
}
void setup() {
  setupRegisters();
}
void loop() {
  //Almost everything is handled by interrupts, lol
}
```

However, when I go to compile, I get the following error message:

```
wiring.c.o (symbol from plugin): In function `__vector_5':

(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__vector_5'

C:\Users\pikec\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_54376\sketch\ATTiny_Frequency_counter.ino.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

exit status 1
Error compiling for board ATtiny25/45/85.
```

What else is utilizing timer0? Do I have any options if I want to reconfigure timer0 without a more sophisticated programmer?

Answer (score 1):

This is because something already declares/uses `TIMER0_OVF_vect`, that is the fifth interrupt vector in `Attiny85`.

Likely you already have `ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect) { ... }` smacked somewhere by a library or something. Comment the `ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect) { ... }` code from your sample and it will compile just fine. Use another timer until you track down the culprit.

I suspect `USI/TWI` implementations already use that interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

This page has some answers: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/44855/arduino-core-structure-and-timer-usage

Timer 0 = timing and delay functions, using the TIMER0_OVF interrupt, and fast PWM at 980 Hz on pins 5 and 6 (PD5 and PD6)

Timer 1 = phase-correct PWM at 490 Hz on pins 9 and 10 (PB1 and PB2)

Timer 2 = phase-correct PWM at 490 Hz on pins 3 and 11 (PD3 and PB3)